# Ember.Select doesn't work

Tags: ember.js

I want to use [Ember.js Select Built-in View](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/built-in-views/) and call the action when select changed . but id doesn't call the action.i create a sample on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/janeg/5/edit?html,js,output) .

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router(function(){
this.route("application");
});
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model:function(){
return [{id:1,name:'hello'},{id:2,name:'goodbye'}];
}

});
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 actions:{
   selectedPosts:function(){
    alert("IM Changed");
  }
 }
});
```

and this the handlebars code :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select"
                contentBinding="content"
                optionLabelPath="content.name"
                optionValuePath="content.id"
                prompt="Pick a person:"
                selectionBinding="selectedPosts"}}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Tip: paste the relevant piece of code in your question to get better response (people are lazy), but it is a very good idea to also include a link to your full sample, as you have done already.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an observer on the selected value:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedPostsChanged:function(){
    alert("IM Changed");
  }.observes("selectedPosts")

});
```

see [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fitezebu/1)

another option would be to sub-class the native Ember select and set a change event on it:

```
App.MySelect = Ember.Select.extend({
  change: function(event){
    this._super(event);
    alert("Changed!");
  }
})
```

see [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fitezebu/2/)